# Ext JS 6 Classic Chart - Truncate Axis

Tags: javascript, extjs

I created a cartesian graph with a continuous numeric axis, [demo](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hg2). Is there a way to use the same numeric data but truncate higher x-axis values in my chart? See below mockup: [image: mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not a solution**, is rather a suggestion, but is too big to put in the comments.

You could format the axis like this:

```
{
    type: 'numeric',
    position: 'top',
    fields: 'start',
    grid: {
        stroke: '#ccc'
    },
    style: 'font-size:3pt',
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 16,
    layout: 'continuous',

    renderer: function(axis,label,layoutContext,lastLabel  ) {
        if (label >14){
            label = '<60';
        } else if (label>13){
            label = '<50';
        } else if (label>12){
            label = '<40';
        } else if (label>11){
            label = '<30';
        } else if (label>10){
            label = '<20';
        }
        return label;
    },
    label:{
         fontSize: '10px' 
    }
```

After the number 10 (or any other value you want) you start to change the display values with the render function.

In this approach you have to modify the store values to match the chart new values, for example, in the record below:

```
{
    "stepNum": 4,
    "name": "Test 1",
    "start": 12,
    "closed": 25
}
```

If the "start" >10 and <20, change it to 11,  if "start" >20 and <30 change it to 12 and so on. ( to change that you could work with the sql if you have access or maybe a convert function in the store )
same thing with the ("closed" + "start"), in this cenario the "adjusted" record would be:

```
{
    "stepNum": 4,
    "name": "Test 1",
    "start": 11,
    "closed": 2
}
```

I hope you understand what i tried to explain, my english its not very good :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.